# How to force system orientation

Tags: java, android, rotation, android-service, screen-rotation

I need my app to force the system orientation to landscape in all installed apps.

I need a way to force a device into a particular screen orientation.

I know of a few apps doing exactly that and I need to know how to.

Comment: Don't use links to google play store. Even if your intentions are good, that feels like spam. Describe what you want instead.

Comment: I removed the links from the question but I'm not sure how clear my question is now

Comment: Your comment to the answer below is a good explanation - you want to create an app that forces other apps (ALL OF THEM) to operate in a specific orientation mode. (p.s. I'd be quite surprised if that's possible - that would be the kind of effect a virus might try to achieve)

Comment: Hello this is a very odd question...

Comment: As I wrote in the question, It is 100% possible and I found a few apps capable of it, no root access or something just plain old native.

Comment: Here is an example

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.eyesfree.setorientation

Comment: If its possible, then what they're doing is probably turning off phone rotation.  I highly doubt this is possible though, unless its done by exploiting a bug

Comment: Yes! thank you the top voted one works perfectly for me!